# What is the difference between PEFT and RAFT?

Tags: transformer-model, large-language-model, fine-tuning, peft

I am studying about finetuning Large Language Models . I came across various techniques and learned about PEFT (Parameter Efficient Finetuning). MOst of the models use these method to finetune. Recently i heared about RAFT Retrieval Augmented Fine Tuning. What is the difference between PEFT and RAFT?

i tried seaching about these in medium articles and blogs but couldn't find. In what way RAFT is better than PEFT and in which specific cases RAFT is useful?